# Backbone.js & twitter template event delegation

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using template forms from bootsnipp. The problem is that I can't delegate click events from this form to backbone. This is the template i'm using:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span4 offset4 well">
      <legend>Please Sign In</legend>
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>Incorrect Username or Password!
            </div>
      <form method="" action="/login" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <input type="text" id="username" class="span4" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" id="password" class="span4" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember Me
            </label>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Sign in</button>
      </form>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my backbone events, I have the following:

```
    events: {
  'click .span4 offset4 well form': 'login',      
 },
```

Why am i not able to get this event?

---

Using the console to inspect the dom, I can capture this button click with

```
$(".btn-block").click(function () {
    alert("here");
   });
```

So i tried changing events to this, with no success:

```
events: {
'click .btn-block': 'login'
}
```

---

Update:
I think what happened was that this particular view was tied to an element:

```
App.Directory = new App.Views.Directory({
   el: $('#display')
});
```

I had put the login form outside of those tags so it had no reference to it. I spent all day trying to figure this out - embarrassing. thanks for the help

Comment: What does the rest of your view look like? Does all that HTML end up inside your view's `el`?

Comment: Once you fix the selector problem that Adrift pointed out (and deleted), it works if everything is structured properly (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4tGA8/). So what are you doing that is different from that fiddle?

Comment: I avoid that problem by (almost) always letting the view create and manage its own `el`. I put a view's `el` *inside* an existing DOM element and almost never use an existing DOM element *as* the view's `el`.